# onBeforeMount stop working after many request

Tags: javascript, api, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I just trying to use this code for adding side client request to my API, it's working nice but after 2 or 3 requests onBeforeMount stop sending the request.

I'm using Nuxt 3 with vue composition API

It's works nice in development mode, this issue  with production mode.

```js
  let poetries = ref([]);

  let pending = ref(true);

  const fetch = async () => {
      const { data: response } = await useLazyFetch(props.api);

      watch(response, (newResponse) => {
          poetries.value = toRaw(newResponse.data);
          pending.value = false;
      })
  }

  onBeforeMount(fetch);
```

is anyone know why this happened.

Trying to make client side request with nuxt 3 and vue composition API with load nuxt server rendering.

```js
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="relative z-20 pb-16 xl:mx-auto xl:max-w-7xl xl:px-8">
            <div class="px-4 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between sm:px-6 lg:px-8 xl:px-0">
                <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white" v-text="title"></h2>
                <a :href="href" class="hidden text-sm font-semibold text-sky-600 hover:text-sky-500 dark:text-sky-300 dark:hover:text-sky-400 sm:block">
                    تصفح المزيد
                </a>
            </div>

            <div  class="flow-root mt-6">
                <div class="-my-2">
                    <div class="box-content relative py-2 overflow-x-auto h-80 xl:overflow-visible">
                        <card-skeleton v-if="pending" :num="5" />
                        
                        <div v-else class="absolute flex px-4 gap-x-8 min-w-screen-xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8 xl:relative xl:grid xl:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8 xl:px-0">
                            <poetry-card  v-for="poetry in poetries" :key="poetry.id" :data="poetry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="px-4 mt-6 sm:hidden">
                <a :href="href" class="block text-sm font-semibold text-sky-600 hover:text-sky-500">
                    تصفح المزيد
                    <span aria-hidden="true"> &rarr;</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        title:  String,
        api:  String,
        href:  String,
    });

    let poetries = ref([]);

    let pending = ref(true);

    const fetch = async () => {
        const { data: response } = await useLazyFetch(props.api);

        watch(response, (newResponse) => {
            poetries.value = toRaw(newResponse.data);
            pending.value = false;
        })
    }

    onBeforeMount(fetch);
</script>
```

Here code for a full component.

Comment: The `watch()` does not seem right. Also, what happens in `useLazyFetch()`?